# Give an access instead of sharing a report in GA

Tags: google-analytics, report, share

I can share access to account, property and view in GA. But when I share a report only its template is shared and the person should setup the report on its own.

So, is it possible to give an access to the reports in view?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom reports can only be shared as a template except if someone has access to the property and view you want them to see. In order to share your report without giving them access you'd need to send them an export of the report or build them a Data Studio dashboard.

If the person does have access to the property and view, they can use your template shortlink and them pick the correct view and see your custom report.